# Angular - Material md-auto complete search suggestions invisible

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, angular-material, md-autocomplete

I have taken the example angular gives on their website and directly put it into my express js app to play around with it and adapt it to what I need. However, for some reason the search suggestions are invisible. I know they are there because I can select them and they will come up in the text box as normal text, but when they are suggestions they do not show up.

I then tried copying and pasting [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angular_material/angular_material_autocomplete.htm) code into my file and running it and I got the same exact issue. Interesting enough, when I put it into codepen it works as it is supposed to.

Does anyone know what could be going on here?
 Is it something to do with using expressjs?

Comment: update: I tried putting the file alone not in my node app directory and it work. I am looking into seeing what interferes.

Comment: so I by-passed this by just serving raw html doing sendfile. before that I was using handlebars. 
I am likely going to need to use some rendering so if anyone knows a solution comment the answer.